# Creating sessionFactory fluent Nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Im working with `MVC4` and using `Fluent Nhibernate` to connect `MSSQL`. As common solutions I have a `createSessionFactory` method for creating the session factory which is like this:

```
public ISessionFactory CreateMSSQLSessionFactory(string server, string DBName, string username, string password)
{
     soFactory =   Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c
                .Server(server).Database(DBName).Username(username).Password(password)))
            .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MvcApplication>())           
            .ExposeConfiguration(c =>
                  c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
            .BuildSessionFactory();

    return soFactory;
}
```

I have tried any kind of mapping but it won't work.
The problem is there when it comes to `.BuildSessionFactory();` it suddenly skip the return sentence. so the `sessionfactory` remains null it seems that it cannot complete building session factory!
The most weird point is that it was perfectly working and suddenly stopped!
I have already tried every single solution which is provided in this site but nothing changes!

Comment: Apply formatting, Clean and Rebuild solution, wrap it in try-catch to look for an exception. It can't "just skip" the return, you know :)

Comment: I assume that when it "skips the return", you are debugging at the time?  I agree with @Shaddix - an exception is the most likely cause.  You need to see what the exception is in order to fix it.  Another thing that can cause the debugger to jump around is mutli-threading.  Visual Studio has a Threads window that can help you keep track of which thread you're currently looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in one of my models I had not declared variables and methods "Virtual", but Visual Studio said naothing to help me.